# Using the Field Calculator in the QGIS 3.4 Python Console

Tags: python, qgis

I am having some trouble running a field calculator processing algorithm from the Python console in QGIS 3.4. I am aiming to remove '/' from the string data in one of the fields and replace them with 'or', so that I can run a split vector algorithm on the field (which currently gets confused as it thinks the '/' is another directory'. I can do this manually using the field calculator but would like to do this in python.

I would like to edit an existing field called 'DESCRIPTIO' using the field calculator expression 'replace("DESCRIPTIO", '/', 'or')' which works when I use the manual field calculator.

Below is the code I am currently using, but I keep getting an error stating **'Incorrect parameter value for FIELD_NAME**' and cannot find any information on the syntax or form that the field name needs to be in. Can anyone help?

```
processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', 
   {"INPUT": fixed1999, 
   "FIELD_NAME": 'DESCRIPTIO' , 
   "FIELD_TYPE": 2,
   "FIELD_LENGTH": 50,
   "FIELD_PRECISION": 3,
   "NEW_FIELD": False ,
   "FORMULA": 'replace( !DESCRIPTIO! , "/" ,  "or")',
   "OUTPUT": source_dir + "/data/1999/fixed.shp"})
```

Comment: Have you tried to escape the backslashes? so "FORMULA": 'replace( !DESCRIPTIO! , "//" ,  "or")', "OUTPUT": source_dir + "//data//1999//fixed.shp"}

Comment: I have just tried it, and unfortunately it still doesn't work. The output has no attributes at all!

Comment: I just noticed you have a space in "FIELD_ NAME" after the underscore -this should be "FIELD_NAME"

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned in my last comment as I also noticed the fault then. I will edit the original post now! Thank you for your help :)